# Android: Problem to write/read file on external storage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to write/read the external storage, after reading some questions here and on internet, exmeple etc.
But i have problem in creating file in the SD, and it doesn't creates and loads, and the `mkdirs` give me the error that it will be ignored:

```
public EditText et;
public Button buttonSave,buttonLoad;
public TextView tv;

public String myData = "";

public File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et = findViewById(R.id.inserimento);
    buttonSave = findViewById(R.id.save);
    buttonLoad = findViewById(R.id.load);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/eliminaCoda");
    dir.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(dir, "Lista.txt");

    buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
                fos.write(et.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            et.setText("");
        }
    });

    buttonLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv.setText(myData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you set the right permissions on manifiest?

Comment: What error you are getting? Please mention logs in your question

Comment: t's not properly an error, when i presso a button save or load, it does not create the file in the SD card, and quen i load it, there isn't nothing in the textview . I Already setted the permission for read/write in external

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add write **uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"** in AndroidManifest.xml file. Also, you have to request for runtime permission.

Please check this demo for runtime permission
[Runtime Permissions in Marshmallow](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/)

Comment: It's not properly an error, when i presso a button save or load, it does not create the file in the SD card, and quen i load it, there isn't nothing in the textview

Comment: yes because now if your device os is greater then M then you have to take permission while runtime and please check attached link

Comment: i add it on tuntine, and granted the permission for read and for write, but nothing, neither save and read appear